# String Concatenation and then append in a loop

Tags: java, string, performance, concatenation, stringbuilder

Found this excerpt from the book "Thinking in Java" written by Bruce Eckel.

> If you try to take shortcuts and do something like `append(a + ": " + c)`
>   , the *compiler will jump in* and start making **more** StringBuilder
>   objects again.

Does that mean that we shouldn't replace a group of append operations with a single line of code; e.g `result.append(i + ": " + 2*i + " ")`?

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    result.append(i);
    result.append(": ");
    result.append(2*i);
    result.append(", ") 
}
```

Does the above statement hold true for Java 8 as well?

Excerpt from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1532499/1465553) on SO: (confused me even more)

> At the point where you're concatenating **in a loop** - that's usually
>   when *the compiler can't substitute* StringBuilder by itself.

Any aspect related to preferred coding style is also welcome.

Comment: `append` is fluent for a reason... Also, the code adds a trailing comma - use a `StringJoiner`

Comment: Sorry, what does that mean? You can ignore trailing comma for the time being.

Comment: Is `StringBuilder.append` a `void` method? Use the return value!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an optimisation the compiler will do for you efficiently.  Stylistically, I would write it like this.

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    result.append(i).append(": ").append(2 * i).append(", ");
}
```

NOTE: IDEs, like IntelliJ, will detect and provide an auto-fix for this as it's a common translation.

Comment: Yes, *stylistically* definitely looks better than `result.append(i + ": " + 2*i + " ")`. But I am afraid the question is about concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the compiler replaces instances of `String` concatenation with `StringBuilder`s, so your line

```
result.append(i + ": " + 2*i + " ");
```

Is changed to

```
result.append(new StringBuilder().append(i).append(": ").append(2*i).append(" ").toString());
```

Like you can see, it just creates *another* `StringBuilder`, which is redundant since you already have one. On top of that, it needs to do so in *every* iteration of the loop, causing a lot of creation and garbage collection for nothing.

So yes, it would definitely be better to just append to the `StringBuilder` you already have directly, instead of concatenating. Whether or not you do this in a single fluent line is mostly a matter of preference.

I'm not sure what the answer you found means by "can't substitute `StringBuilder`". They probably meant that it won't re-use your existing builder (and instead create a new one).

This is still valid for Java 8, although since then there are alternative streaming methods, like one of the other answers shows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we should still use chained appends instead of string concatenation when performance is crucial.

However, whenever performance is not crucial, we should strive for code readability, clarity and reuse. Thus my stylistic choice would be:

```
IntStream
    .range(0, 25)
    .map(i, String.format("%d: %d", i, i*2)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```